# Why does custom map of <c-w><space> cause mapping delay in terminal mode?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I'm using `<c-w><space>` to open current terminal buffer in a new tab:

```
tnoremap <c-w><space> <c-w>:tab split<cr>
```

This map cause `<c-w><c-w>` trigger mapping delay in terminal mode, why would that happen? Are there any relation between `<space>` (0x20) and `<c-w>` (0x17) ?

The `<c-w><space>` works fine, it doesn't trigger mapping delay.

I have created an rc file with this single command and tested it with `vim -Nu rc`, the result didn't change.

FWIW, I also use this map in normal mode:

```
nnoremap <c-w><space> :tab split<cr>
```

It works fine, it doesn't affect `<c-w><c-w>`  int normal mode.

I'm using vim8.1-2300, ubuntu 18.04.4, zsh 5.4.2

Comment: For some reason, `C-w` is not written in the typeahead immediately (not printed in the `'showcmd'` area).  Maybe Vim waits for `&timeoutlen` ms to determine whether the key must be remapped or executed with its default meaning (start a C-W command, as set by `'termwinkey'`).  I guess that the key assigned to `'termwinkey'` is handled differently in Terminal-Job mode compared to `C-w` in normal mode.  You could somewhat get around the timeout by installing this mapping: `tno <c-w><c-w> <c-w><c-w>`.

Comment: @user938271 Nice observation, I tested it with `2000` timeoutlen, it woks like you described, the workaround works too! I think you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, `C-w` is not written in the typeahead immediately (not printed in the `'showcmd'` area).

It seems that Vim waits for `&timeoutlen` ms to determine whether the key must be remapped or executed with its default meaning (start a C-W command).  I guess that the key assigned to `'termwinkey'` is handled differently in Terminal-Job mode compared to `C-w` in normal mode.

You could somewhat get around the timeout by installing this mapping:

```
tno <c-w><c-w> <c-w><c-w>
```

This works under the assumption that you didn't reset `'termwinkey'`, and as a result Vim uses `<C-w>` to start a C-W command.  This wouldn't work if you've reset the option to, let's say, `<C-s>`, and you press `<C-s><C-w>` to focus another window.

For something more reliable, you could try this:

```
augroup termwinkey_no_timeout
    au!
    au TerminalWinOpen * let b:_twk = &l:twk == '' ? '<c-w>' : &l:twk
      \ | exe printf('tno <buffer><nowait> %s<c-w> %s<c-w>', b:_twk , b:_twk)
      \ | unlet! b:_twk
augroup END
```